# Java List<Integer> wrapper that internally stores an int[]

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I am looking for a way to create a java `List<Integer>` interface, which doesn't store Integer as reference type but internally stores `int[]` or other form of continuous buffer, and converts them to boxed `Integer` type when needed.

Is this possible by using standard library?

or

should I implement a `List<Integer>` interface in my own class?

or

Java does the optimization already?

I tried `Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3,4})`, but it creates a list containing single array.

I am actually trying to optimize a leetcode program to hell, so standard library one liners are much appreciated.

Comment: "*Is this possible by using standard library?*" No. "*should I implement a List<Integer> interface in my own class?*" That's personal preference. "*Java does the optimization already?*" No, but [project Valhalla](https://openjdk.org/projects/valhalla/) will eventually make such optimizations unnecessary; it's being worked on, but will be some years.

Comment: "I am actually trying to optimize a leetcode program to hell" knowing the leetcode problems, are you sure you're optimizing in the correct place and not missing some really inefficient algorithm somewhere else?

Comment: "*I am actually trying to optimize a leetcode program to hell*" Then don't use List in the first place. It's basically a convenient API over the top of an array. Just use the array directly.

Comment: Not exactly, but there is [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

Comment: @Frederico I got the answer. I am optimizing it to reach 100% performance percentile.

Comment: @Michael the problem template returns List<Integer> so I cant change that.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, in leetcode itself, by going to performance chart of submitted programs and clicking on first bar. (Why didn't I think of this before?)

Here's the relevant part of "sample 0ms submission" which minimally implements the list.

```java
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    // Problem solution skipped

    class MyList extends AbstractList<Integer> {
        private int[] arr;
        private int left;
        private int right;

        public MyList(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
            this.arr = arr;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            // NOTE: This doesn't do bounds checks. Do bounds checks in production code.
            return arr[left+index];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return right-left;
        }
    }
}
```

So the `AbstractList` class seems to exist for this type of uses.

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the List interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface backed by a "random access" data store (such as an array). For sequential access data (such as a linked list), AbstractSequentialList should be used in preference to this class.

> To implement an unmodifiable list, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the get(int) and size() methods.

> To implement a modifiable list, the programmer must additionally override the set(int, E) method (which otherwise throws an UnsupportedOperationException). If the list is variable-size the programmer must additionally override the add(int, E) and remove(int) methods.

Edit: Thanks @Holger for pointing out it doesn't check bounds in `get()` method. In the context of Leetcode it's fine. But do your bounds checks in production code.

Comment: _"So the AbstractList class seems to exist for this very purpose."_, not really, the `AbstractList` class exists for common code of `List` implementations like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Vector`, and _also_ your own implementations.

Comment: You should not use this implementation in production code. It does not verify any parameters but allows to silently get away with invalid parameters in an unintended way, i.e. passing indices outside the valid range allow to access array elements outside the range represented by the `List`.